# Inline Text Editor not working on textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a plugin Inplace Editor(https://github.com/wbotelhos/inplace) for inline editing for a profile page of a website. For some texts in profile page, I need to use `<textarea>` instead of `<input type="text">` to save the details. The plugin does have an option to use `<textarea>` instead of `<input>` tag, but for some reason it doesn't work. Plugin doesn't have much documentation either. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="inplace-textarea">Enter your introduction</div>

jQuery('.inplace-textarea').inplace({
    fieldType: 'textarea',
    typeful: [
        'color',
        'date',
        'datetime',
        'datetime-local',
        'email',
        'hidden',
        'month',
        'number',
        'password',
        'range',
        'search',
        'tel',
        'text',
        'textarea',
        'time',
        'url',
        'week'
       ]
});

/*!
* Inplace - An inplace editor
*
* The MIT License
*
* @author:  Washington Botelho
* @doc:     wbotelhos.com/inplace
* @version: 0.1.0
*
*/

;
(function($) {
'use strict';

$.inplace = {
buttonOrder:   ['cancel', 'save'],
cancel:        true,
cancelClass:   'inplace__cancel',
cancelValue:   'Cancel',
checkable:     ['checkbox', 'radio'],
fieldClass:    'inplace__field',
fieldName:     undefined,
fieldTemplate: '{name}',
fieldType:     'text',
method:        'PATCH',
save:          true,
saveClass:     'inplace__save',
saveValue:     'Save',
selectable:    ['select-one', 'select-multiple'],

typeful: [
'color',
'date',
'datetime',
'datetime-local',
'email',
'hidden',
'month',
'number',
'password',
'range',
'search',
'tel',
'text',
'textarea',
'time',
'url',
'week'
]
}

$.fn.inplace = function(options) {
return this.each(function() {
return (new $.inplace.Inplace(this, options))._create();
});
}

$.inplace.Inplace = (function() {
var Inplace = function(element, options) {
this.el      = $(element);
this.element = element;

this.options = $.extend({}, $.inplace, options, this.el.data());
}

Inplace.prototype = {
_activate: function() {
var field = this._field();

this
.el
.off('click.inplace.el')
.addClass('inplace--active')
.html(field)
.trigger('inplace:activate', this.element);

for (var i = 0; i < this.options.buttonOrder.length; i++) {
var value = this.options.buttonOrder[i];

if (this.options[value]) {
this._build(value, 'button').appendTo(this.el);
}
}

var actived = $('.inplace--active').not(this.el);

for (var i = 0; i < actived.length; i++) {
actived.data('inplace')._deactivate();
}

field.trigger('focus');
},

_bindCancel: function() {
this.el.on('click.inplace.cancel', '[data-inplace-cancel]', 
this._deactivate.bind(this));
},

_bindClick: function() {
this.el.on('click.inplace.el', this._activate.bind(this));
},

_bindField: function() {
var typeful = [];

for (var i = 0; i < $.inplace.typeful.length; i++) {
typeful.push('[type="' + $.inplace.typeful[i] + '"]');
}

var fields = typeful.join(',');

this._bindKey('keypress.inplace.field', 13, fields, 
this._request.bind(this));
this._bindKey('keyup.inplace.field', 27, fields, 
this._deactivate.bind(this));
},

_bindKey: function(event, keycode, fields, callback) {
this.el.on(event, fields, function(evt) {
if ((evt.which || evt.keyCode) === keycode) {
callback();
}
});
},

_bindSave: function() {
this.el.on('click.inplace.save', '[data-inplace-save]', 
this._request.bind(this));
},

_build: function(kind, type) {
var options = {
'class': this.options[kind + 'Class'],
type:    type,
value:   this.options[kind + 'Value']
};


if (kind === 'field') {
var attributes = this.el.data('attributes');

if (attributes) {
options = $.extend({}, options, attributes);
}
}

options['data-inplace-' + kind] = '';

return $('<input />', options);
},

_create: function() {
this._bindClick();
this._bindField();
this._bindSave();
this._bindCancel();

this.el.data('inplace', this);

return this;
},

_deactivate: function() {
this._bindClick();

this
.el
.removeClass('inplace--active')
.html(this.element.getAttribute('data-field-value'))
.trigger('inplace:deactivate', this.element);
},

_done: function(json) {
this._deactivate();

this.options.fieldValue = json[this.options.fieldName];

this.element.setAttribute('data-field-value', this.options.fieldValue);
this.el.trigger('inplace:done', json);
},

_field: function() {
return this._build('field', this.options.fieldType);
},

_request: function() {
$.ajax(this._requestOptions()).done(this._done.bind(this));
},

_requestOptions: function() {
var data = {};
var name = this.options.fieldTemplate.replace('{name}',     
this.options.fieldName);

data[name] = this.el.find('[data-inplace-field]').val();

return { data: data, method: this.options.method, url: this.options.url };
}
};

return Inplace;
})();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please update your question and tell us what is occurring and what you expect to occur.  As it stands, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: *`data-field-type`: Field type that can be `text` or `select`;*

Comment: Not without changing the plugin, which has this line: `return $('<input />', options);` - you could probably change the plugin to check for `fieldType=='textarea'` and return a textarea instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function() {
      $('#editable-notes').inlineEdit();
    });

    $.fn.inlineEdit = function() {
      var $wrapper = $(this),
        $text = $wrapper.find('.editable-text'),
        $input = $wrapper.find('.editable-input');

      $input.val($text.text());

      var setInputHeight = function() {
        $input.height(0);
        $input.height($input[0].scrollHeight);
      };

      $text.on('click', function() {
        $wrapper.addClass('edit-state');
        $input.val($text.text());
        $input.focus();
        setInputHeight();

        $input[0].selectionStart = $input[0].selectionEnd = $input[0].value.length;
      });

      $input.on('keyup', function() {
        setInputHeight();
      });

      $input.on('blur', function() {
        $wrapper.removeClass('edit-state');
        $text.html($input.val());


      });
    };
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.editable-text,
.editable-input {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.editable-text {
  padding: 0.75em;
}

.editable-input {
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.editable-text:hover {
  background: #fffbe1;
  cursor: text;
}

.editable-input {
  display: none;
}

.editable-wrapper.edit-state .editable-text {
  display: none;
}

.editable-wrapper.edit-state .editable-input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editable-notes" class="editable-wrapper">
  <pre class="editable-text">
Please
edit
me</pre>
  <textarea class="editable-input"></textarea>
</div>
```